# Does repetition in the following sequence of words display symbolism, emphasis, or both?

Tags: repetition, emphasis, literary-device

The sequence is "**How much wood could a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck would?**" I am wondering if repetition, particularly of the word "wood", would display symbolism or any other kind of literary device.

Comment: If the quote were written as "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?" [note the last word!] it might be easier to parse. *Woodchuck* is a [type of marmot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog) and the verb *chuck* means [*throw*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chuck).

Comment: The quote is written as said, with "would" at the ending - which is why I found it so confusing.  I think it was done purposefully.

Comment: Or maybe my teacher misspelled it, though I don't think he would have.

Comment: I've just messaged him on Facebook; yes, it was intentional.

Comment: Heh, I can't help but wonder if this question relates to whether rubber baby buggy bumpers have been approved by the Consumer Product Safety Commission. -- As a serious question (and ignoring spelling), I would have to say it is worded neither symbolically nor for emphasis.  It is simply a tongue twister, worded so that the words will make grammatical sense yet be difficult to say together.

Comment: The would doesn't make any grammatical sense though, so I was thrown off. And my teacher did state it has some meaning.

Comment: The "would" I refer to in my previous comment was the one at the end.

Comment: OK, so your teacher has deliberately misquoted the sentence, and then asked for literary analysis, which is off-topic here. I don't think we can answer this, although I'm open to persuasion and five other people can re-open the question too.

Comment: Could you please clarify why literary analysis is off-topic here, and suggest some places I could ask about it? I don't mean to sound uptight or anything like that; I just merely want to know what this would mean.

Comment: No, but my friend apparently did that as a joke.

Comment: I apologize for the spam he caused.

Comment: @ShruHooWoo thanks for that. Be careful who you allow to access your account. You can get banned for those types of posts. Good luck.

Comment: I've locked down my security now; changed password and more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**References:**

https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/sentence-style/2/sentence-emphasis/
http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-symbolism.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_much_wood_would_a_woodchuck_chuck
http://thepoetrypundit.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/alliteration-assonance-and-consonance.html

> Does repetition in the following sequence of words display symbolism,
>   emphasis, or both?
>
> How much wood could a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck would

This is an english tongue twister using mainly consonance and assonance (uck uck, ood ould).  This would be used to warm up before a stage performance or as a fun tongue twister in a primary school english lesson.

There is no symbolism, the wood is referring to actual wood, the woodchuck is a small creature.  There are no metaphor or allegory.

Position and repetition are the key tools for emphasis.  I suppose that the repetition of the word "wood" implies that wood plays a strong part, also the position of the words "how much" indicates a possibly philosophical question.

However, there really is no depth here, there is no more symbolism or meaning here that there is with other tongue twisters such as "peter piper picked a peck of pickled pepper".  There is no Peter, the pepper is not symbollic, the sentence is quite simply built to emphasize sounds, not hold any deeper poetical meaning.

**Use of Would**

If you teacher is being facetious and trying to play "would" for "wood" then the sentence could be viewed as:

- How much wood could a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck **Would**

If "Would" was a person or thing then the wood chuck could try and chuck them

- How much wood could a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could. **Chuck would**

If a period was placed after "could" then the sentence will terminate there implying "if a wood chuck was able to".  The next short sentence *with emphasis* implies that someone called Chuck certainly would try it.  Would being the conditional tense of will.

There was an old game that held a similar riddle:

> https://lparchive.org/Monkey-Island-2/Update%203/
>
> A woodchuck could chuck no amount of wood since a woodchuck can't
>   chuck wood.
>
> But if a woodchuck could chuck and would chuck some amount of wood,
>   how much wood would a woodchuck chuck?
>
> Even if a woodchuck could chuck wood, and even if a woodchuck would
>   chuck wood, should a woodchuck chuck wood?
>
> A woodchuck should chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood, as long as a
>   wood chuck would chuck wood.

Which, is ridiculously abstract and if this is the answer then ask your teacher if they know the meaning of unreasonable or absurd.

Comment: I would say my teacher's a bit eccentric.

Comment: Well interesting at least :)